# How to get Master Chain Code

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, nbitcoin

I'm using NBitcoin and I created an `ExtKey` object. Now I need to get the Master Chain Code (see page 89 of Mastering Bitcoin for a good explanation) for this HD node. How do I do this?

According to Mastering Bitcoin a root seed is used with HMAC-SHA512 to create a 512-bits output. The left 256 bits are used for the master private key, the right 256 bits are used for the master chain code. When I call `GetBytes()` on my `ExtKey` object, however, it returns a byte[74] array. This corresponds to 592 bits. I don't know what the extra 80 bits are so I can't just take the right 256 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a pull request that adds a property to `ExtKey` and `ExtPubKey` that allows you to call the `ChainCode` property. See [pull request 156](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/pull/156).

It has been merged into [NBitcoin 3.0.0.28 which is available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NBitcoin/).

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few things what you can do, I noted what you need in comment:

```
var masterPrivateKey = new ExtKey();
var masterPublicKey = masterPrivateKey.Neuter();

// This is what you need:
var masterMainNetPrivateKey = masterPrivateKey.GetWif(Network.Main);
var masterTestNetPrivateKey = masterPrivateKey.GetWif(Network.TestNet);

var masterMainNetPublicKey = masterPublicKey.GetWif(Network.Main);
var masterTestNetPublicKey = masterPublicKey.GetWif(Network.TestNet);
```

You might want to check the [corresponding section of the C# Bitcoin book](https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain/content/key_storage_and_generation/key_generation.html).

Comment: No, that's not what I need. WIF and Chain Code are two completely different things. WIF is just a way to encode a private key.

Comment: Anyway, I added a change to NBitcoin that exposes the chain code through a property, see PR 156 https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/pull/156. It has been merged into NBitcoin 3.0.0.28, available on NuGet.